# Layers peeling off in resin prints

Tags: troubleshooting, resin

I'm having some issues with my Creality HALOT-ONE. As you can see in the photo, it seems that the layers after the bottom layer are peeling off. I have to remark that the bottom layer sticks very well to the printing bed.

This issue always happens in the next layer after the bottom ones. I have never experienced this in the middle of a print.
Also, it doesn't happen in all the prints. It seems that it appears near the middle of the resin container. I haven't seen it near the corners of the vat yet.

I can imagine that the subsequent layers don't stick properly to the bottom one, but I don't have any clue why.

I'm using the Creality 3D Printer Standard Grey resin.

My bottom exposure time is 46 sec. And my layer exposure time is 3sec. The distance that the plate moves after a layer is 5 cm.

[image: Photo of a 3D resin model with the layers after the bottom are peeling off]

Comment: Are your bottom layers that are intentionally over exposed the same number or more as the raft thickness? You don’t want “green” layers in the raft. It can be thin and still do its job.

Comment: I didnt consider that, ill try reducing the number of bottom layers. But i changed the fep recently (i have been using the original) and the problem seem to be over

Answer (score 2):

I don't know your machine or resin but here are some likely fixes:

- `wait_time_before_cure`
  When the build plate moves down and squeezes the resin against the FEP, the entire machine bends and the build plate only slowly approaches the intended height
  **Remedy**: add e.g. 5 s of wait_time_before_cure
- level your build plate
  The bottom_cure_time might compensate for a skewed build plate but the first regular layer may not
  **Remedy**: level your build plate
- position of models
  Models fail when placed in the wrong position. Follow this order when placing models on the build plate. When you put a model in position 3 and none in 1 or 2, a failure is more likely.
  By the way, model/models can cover most of the build plate as pealing forces are very rarely an issue.

[image]

Not related to your issue but things to consider:

- `bottom_cure_time`
  It's not necessary to have 46 s `bottom_cure_time`. 2-3 times the `regular_cure_time` is fine, so in your case e.g. 7 s. It saves your light source from overheating and removing your models from the build plate becomes much easier.
- `lift_height`

> The distance that the plate moves after a layer is 5 cm

not sure what you mean. `lift_height` is typically 5 mm max, which also saves you a lot of print time.

Comment: It was a Fep Problem. I was using the original one, i changed it and the problem disapeared :D

Comment: @Germán - please post your comment as an actual *answer* (rather than a comment) and expand upon it. Then mark it as accepted (after waiting 48 hours). It may help others who have the same problem. Thanks.